# linear algebra after the given roots has been calculate of the eigenvalues of a matrix. Which root are corresponding to a given eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A matrix of polynomial with power 2 or higher. After the roots are calculated how to figure out which roots are corresponding to the given eigenvalue of each joint of the matrix?

:Edit

I was asking about if there was canonical ordering of the eigenvalues

Comment: I don’t understand. Each root (of the characteristic polynomial) is an eigenvalue. There is no canonical ordering of which root is assigned to “which” eigenvalue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thx, I was asking if there was an canonical ordering of eigenvalues.  You help me to a greater understanding of the eigenvalues.